# A Lie group associated to a matrix via semi direct product

Tags: group-theory, matrices, lie-groups, abstract-algebra

Assume  that $A \in M_{n}(\mathbb{R}) $ is  a matrix. Then $A$ generates a one parameter (with parameter $t\in \mathbb{R}$) family of group automorphisms of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$  with $x\mapsto e^{tA}x,\;\;x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Here $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is  counted  as  a group with the usual addition. So  every  matrix $A$ define an action of $\mathbb{R}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. with some abuse of  notations, this action is  denoted by $A$, again.
The  corresponding semi direct product gives us a  Lie  group $G_{A}=\mathbb{R}^{n} \rtimes_{A} \mathbb{R}$.

> Is it true to say that $G_{A} \simeq G_{B}$, as two lie groups  $\iff$ $A$  an  $B$ are two similar matrices?

Comment: they are isomorphic Lie groups iff $A$ is similar to $tB$ for some $t$. This is immediate if $A$ is invertible (because $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be recognized as the derived subgroup), and more generally when $A^2\neq 0$ (because $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be recognized as the centralizer of the derived subgroup), and the case $A^2=0$ can be dealt with an ad hoc argument.

Comment: @YCor  Thank you for your comment. Can I ask you to expand this comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As abstract Lie groups, if you take $A=(2)$ and $B=(3)$ as $1 \times 1$ matrices, the Lie groups $G_A$ and $G_B$ are isomorphic, to the 2-dimensional nonabelian simply connected Lie group.

Comment: thank you for your answer.   What about $n>1$?

Comment: I think that the center acts by adjoint action on the Lie algebra giving you that $A$ and $B$ must agree up to scaling.

Comment: do you mean $G_{A}\simeq G_{B} $ implies that $A=\lambda B$ for  some  scalar?

Comment: while it seems that two similar matrices produces two isomorphisc Lie groups.

Comment: Sorry, not the center, but the quotient Lie algebra acts on the ideal as $A$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^n$, but with a basis of the quotient only defined up to rescaling. So $A=\lambda B$. I thought you were asking if $A$ and $B$ where conjugate (no), but if you ask for similar: yes.